# trouble while making install monetdb5

Tags: monetdb

I've the following error when running `make` while installing monetdb5

```
make[9]: Entering directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras/jaql/parser'
/bin/bash ../../../../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -    I../../../..  -I. -I../ -I./../ -I../../../mal -I./../../../mal -I../../../optimizer -I./../../../optimizer -I../../../../common/options -I./../../../../common/options -I../../../../common/stream -I./../../../../common/stream -I../../../../gdk -I./../../../../gdk  -DLIBJAQLP  -g -O2   -c -o libjaqlp_la-jaql.tab.lo `test -f 'jaql.tab.c' || echo './'`jaql.tab.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../.. -I. -I../ -I./../ -I../../../mal -I./../../../mal -I../../../optimizer -I./../../../optimizer -I../../../../common/options -I./../../../../common/options -I../../../../common/stream -I./../../../../common/stream -I../../../../gdk -I./../../../../gdk -DLIBJAQLP -g -O2 -c jaql.tab.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libjaqlp_la-jaql.tab.o
y.tab.c: In function 'jaqlparse':
y.tab.c:1684:32: error: 'scanner' undeclared (first use in this function)
y.tab.c:1684:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[9]: *** [libjaqlp_la-jaql.tab.lo] Error 1
make[9]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras/jaql/parser'
make[8]: *** [all] Error 2
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras/jaql/parser'
make[7]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras/jaql'
make[6]: *** [all] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras/jaql'
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras'
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5/extras'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb/monetdb5'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lfopa/opt/monetdb'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The configuration was good according to the readme file here are last line of the configuration

```
* Enabled/disabled build options:
    strict     is disabled (by default)
    assert     is disabled (by default)
    debug      is disabled (by default)
    optimize   is disabled (by default)
    developer  is disabled (by default)
    instrument is disabled (by default)
    profile    is disabled (by default)

* Enabled/disabled components:
    gdk       is enabled
    monetdb5  is enabled
    sql       is enabled
    jaql      is enabled
    geom      is disabled (geos library required for geom module)
    gsl       is enabled
    fits      is disabled (cfitsio library not found)
    rdf       is disabled (by default)
    datacell  is disabled (by default)
    odbc      is enabled
    jdbc      is enabled
    control   is enabled
    testing   is enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message. The trouble occurs when compiling `jaqlparse` which is a function needed to install the extension jaql`. Since I'm not interesting by this extension, I solved the problem by disabling`jaql` extension when configuring monetdb

```
./configure --diseable-jaql
sudo make
sudo make install
```